# Joining 2 Tables using a wildcard

Tags: sql

I need to Join 2 tables but there is not a true common field. In Table A the ID field contains the ID from Table B BUT it has additional characters before and after the ID.

TableA ID
. a J123 00

TableB ID
J123

Need to Join B to A based on the J123 in Table B

How can i write a Join statement to join table B to table A?

Using SQL Sever 2008

Comment: What have you tried? Show us what you've done so far to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: Tried using a widlcard % and Like rather than =

Comment: Join TableB on TableA_ID Like '%' TableB_ID '%'

Answer (score 5):

You can use `like`.  Not good for performance but it can work:

```
select *
from tableA a join
     tableB b
     on a.id like '%' + b.id + '%';
```

Do note that this will likely do unexpected things.  For instance, all ids with a value of `10` will match those with `100`.  Unless you have some way of knowing which characters in a are actually the `id` field, you probably have to live with this.

And, this situation happens when people want the primary key of a table to mean something.  This is a good argument for anonymous primary keys.  No one gets the idea to try to interpret it.  If someone wants information about it, they can look it up in the appropriate table.

EDIT:

You can write this using an `exists` clause if you like:

```
select *
from tableA a
where exists (select 1 from tableB b where  a.id like '%' + b.id + '%');
```

This will not produce duplicate values from `tableA` when there is more than one matching value.

Comment: Rather then using a join is it possible to select records from tableA based on a sub query where a.id IN (Select '%' + b.id + '%' FROM tableB b)