# SQL: Joining tables using wildcards

Tags: postgresql, join, duplicates, wildcard

When I join 2 tables

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col3 
from t1
left join t2
on t1.col2=t2.col3
```

Then I don't get any duplicate rows. However, when I try joining
tables using wildcards:

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col3 
from t1
left join t2
on t1.col2 like '%'||t2.col3
```

Then I'll get duplicate values. I saw this post that I think is
getting me somewhere but I couldn't really understand the solution.

[Joining 2 Tables using a wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829210/joining-2-tables-using-a-wildcard)

It says I can use `exists` to get rid of duplicate values. I also
don't really understand his query. Here is the query in the other
post:

```
select *
from tableA a
where exists (select 1 from tableB b where  a.id like '%' + b.id + '%');
```

What does the `select 1 from tableB` do?
I'm using PostgreSQL

This is what I've tried even though I don't understand it and still gives me duplicates:

```
select t1.col1,t1.col2,t2.col3
from t1
left join t2
on t1.col2 like '%'||t2.col3 
where exists (select 1 from t2 where t1.col2 like '%'||t2.col3)
```

Comment: Looks like a classic  [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of talking about solution tell us about your actual problem that you're trying to solve. That will save time and down votes for everybody.

Comment: Hey thanks. This is what I'm trying to accomplish: I want to join 2 tables by using wildcards without getting duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DISTINCT` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col3 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.col2 LIKE '%'||t2.col3;
```